# Convert TStream to String?

Tags: string, delphi, stream, delphi-10.4-sydney

In Delphi 10.4, I try to convert a `TStream` to a `string` with this code:

```
function MyStreamToString(aStream: TStream): string;
var
  SS: TStringStream;
begin
  if aStream <> nil then
  begin
    SS := TStringStream.Create('');
    try
      SS.CopyFrom(aStream, 0); // Exception: TStream.Seek not implemented
      Result := SS.DataString;
    finally
      SS.Free;
    end;
  end else
  begin
    Result := '';
  end;
end;
```

But in this code line, I get an exception "TStream.Seek not implemented": `SS.CopyFrom(aStream, 0);`

Why? How can I "heal" this code?

Comment: In what sense do you want to copy the string to a stream? Is the stream a stream of bytes that encodes text in UTF-8? Or is it a stream of bytes that encodes text in UTF-16LE? Or in Windows-1252? Or do you want to obtain a string with the raw bytes represented as hex? Or is the stream a bitmap image and you want the string to contain a nice summary of the image ("A red cottage at a lake. A man is standing outside the door.")?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, you are right, when I pass it a `TMemoryStream` then everything is OK. Thank you for the clarification the `TStream` is just an abstract base class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means you are passing your function a `TStream` object that does not implement `Seek()` at all.  Such as if you are passing in an actual `TStream` object and not a derived object, like `TFileStream`, `TMemoryStream`, etc, for instance:

```pascal
var
  Strm: TStream;
begin
  Strm := TStream.Create; // <-- ERROR
  try
    MyStreamToString(Strm);
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

`TStream` is an abstract base class, it should *never* be instantiated directly.

In this case, the 32-bit `Seek()` method in the base `TStream` class calls the 64-bit `Seek()` method, but will raise that "Seek not implemented" exception if the 64-bit `Seek()` has not been overridden.  A `TStream`-derived class *must* `override` either the 32-bit `Seek()` or the 64-bit `Seek()`, and the overridden method *must not* call the base `TStream` method it is overriding.

So, make sure you are passing in a *valid* stream object to your function.